# How can I convert a huge Resultset of 10 million records to a list in java?

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to fetch the resultset into a `Set` so that I can remove the duplicates and put it in a separate table to ease out the sanitizing process .

But when I try using this :

```
while (rs.next()) {
    set.add(new ABC(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5),
        rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10),
        rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15),
        rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20),
        rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), rs.getString(24), rs.getString(25),
        rs.getString(26)));
}
```

After 1 million records, Java throws a System overhead GC error?
Any alternative?

Comment: Why? What did you expect? Why not just process the `ResultSet` you already have, row by row?

Comment: because I need to findout duplicate in the resultset and putting it in a set for that ...overriding hashcode and equals

Comment: Clarified in the question, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You might be better off leveraging the database for that. Just find a query or stored proc that can find your duplicates without needing you to load all the data in memory

Comment: So, this is not possible in java by any alternative ?

Comment: What about fetching the data by chunks?

Comment: Some simple arithmetiics: you have 10 million rows. Each row has 26 strings. Let's assume they're all tiny and only consume 25 bytes. Let's ignore the memory used by Set entries. All this would consume 10,000,000 x 25 x 26 bytes = 6.5 GB of memory. You probably don't have that much of memory. And the strings probably consume much more than that. And the set and the ABC instances adds memory too.

Comment: In general you should never attempt to process an entire result set in memory. You can't rely on fitting it all into memory, and it is wasteful to transport it all over the network when you can do the processing at the server side. SQL already provides you with filters, groupings, group totals, all kinds of things. Use them.

Comment: I think the error has more to do with object creation everytime I iterate a resultset..

Comment: More to do with it than what? There is nothing *else* it has to do with. And from your description it isn't *necessary* to do it in Java.

Comment: Maybe if you increased the Xmx size it might help, Even I believe that you to fetch data into chunks

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 8):

If your end desired result is a new table whose data is the original table minus duplicates, then this is an operation which should be completely handled in your database, not in Java:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable (col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50), ..., col26 varchar(50));
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, ..., col26)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ..., col26
FROM originalTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do this in any other way than loading all the data into memory, and there is some redundancy in the strings you are extracting from the database, String interning might help.

Use a utility method to handle nulls properly, then wrap all getString calls with it.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    set.add(new ABC(intern(rs.getString(1)), intern(rs.getString(2)), 
intern(rs.getString(3)), intern(rs.getString(4)), intern(rs.getString(5)),
        intern(rs.getString(6)), intern(rs.getString(7)), intern(rs.getString(8)), 
intern(rs.getString(9)), intern(rs.getString(10)),
        intern(rs.getString(11)), intern(rs.getString(12)), intern(rs.getString(13)), 
intern(rs.getString(14)), intern(rs.getString(15)),
        intern(rs.getString(16)), intern(rs.getString(17)), intern(rs.getString(18)), 
intern(rs.getString(19)), intern(rs.getString(20)),
        intern(rs.getString(21)), intern(rs.getString(22)), intern(rs.getString(23)), 
intern(rs.getString(24)), intern(rs.getString(25)),
        intern(rs.getString(26))));
}       

private String intern(String string) {
         return string == null ? null : string.intern();
}
```

Running on Java 9 or higher will also help, as strings on average use less memory with these versions.